# Is it possible to install bioconductor package 'rain' in R Jupyter notebook?

Tags: r, bioinformatics, jupyter-notebook, bioconductor, installation-package

I want to install the [bioconductor rain package](https://www.bioconductor.org/packages/devel/bioc/html/rain.html) for R in Jupyter notebook.

I am not able to install this package in Jupyter notebook following instructions given on the website linked above - in an R Jupiter notebook:

```
source("https://bioconductor.org/biocLite.R")
biocLite("rain")
```

I get the following error:

```
Warning message:
In install.packages(pkgs = doing, lib = lib, ...): installation of package ‘gmp’ had non-zero exit statusWarning message:
In install.packages(pkgs = doing, lib = lib, ...): installation of package ‘rain’ had non-zero exit status
```

I was able to install a different bioconductor package in Jupyter ([DESeq2](https://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/DESeq2.html)) using the following - in command line:

```
conda install bioconductor-deseq2
```

But this method does not work for the rain package, because, unlike deseq2, rain is not on the anaconda cloud.

Is it possible to install a bioconductor package not on the anaconda cloud (like the rain package) in Jupyter, and, if so, how?

Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How should I deal with "package 'xxx' is not available (for R version x.y.z)" warning?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25721884/how-should-i-deal-with-package-xxx-is-not-available-for-r-version-x-y-z-wa)

Comment: Not quite the same - my problem has to do with installing R packages  specifically for use in the Jupyter Notebook software.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a solution to my problem. There are two ways to install IRkernel: 1) using CRAN+Github (instructions: http://irkernel.github.io/) and 2) as a conda package called r-irkernel. The later method, which I had used, installs and runs conda's own version of R, which has more limited functionality in terms of packages that can be installed. Whereas the CRAN+Github method allows Jupyter to use the version of R already installed on your computer with any packages that it can run.